# Open files with common name part

Tags: windows, excel, vba

First of all, please excuse my shortcomings in presenting my issue as I haven't got much knowledge in VBA. Your help would be kindly appreciated.

I am working on a project that would imply putting the content of three different Excel files from three different sub-folders into one Excel file, and then run some macros in order to process the data they contain. Since I've already set the processing macros, my issue relies in importing the content correctly.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't have the exact names of the files I would like to open, and that they would change each month. Therefore, I can't use the "WorkBooks.Open" command that requires a precise name. However, the files have predictable name formats. For instance, one of the sub-folders will be comprised of files named "XXX-jan2013.xls", another one "january2013-XXX" and the last one "XXX-01/2013".

My goal would be to input the month and year manually, for instance “01/2013”, and then open all the files containing "January”, “jan” or “01" in their names.

Here’s what I have so far, with comments:

```
Sub ChosenDate()
‘It aims at opening a box in which the desired month would be written manually
Dim InputDate As String
‘These are the indications the user will get
    InputDate = InputBox(Prompt:="Please choose a month.", _
            Title:="Date", Default:="MM/YYYY")
‘In case the person forgets to write what he’s asked to
          If InputDate = "MM/YYYY" Or _
          InputDate = vbNullString Then
          Exit Sub
‘If he does it correctly, I call the second Sub
         Else: Call FilesOpening
        End If
End Sub
‘So far, everything works fine

Public Sub FilesOpening()
‘This one aims at opening the chosen files
Dim ThisFile               As String
Dim Files                    As String
 ‘Defining the folder in which the file is, as it can change from a computer to another
ThisFile = ThisWorkbook.Path
‘Here’s where I start struggling and where the macro doesn’t work anymore
‘If I wanted to open all the files of the folder, I would just write that:
Files = Dir(ThisFile & "\*.xls")
‘You never know…
On Error Resume Next
‘Creating the Loop
Do While Files <> vbNullString
Files = Dir
Set wbBook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Files)
Loop
End Sub
‘But it doesn’t look inside of sub-folders, neither does it consider the date
Sub DataProcess()
‘This one is fine, except I can’t find a way to name the files correctly. Here’s the beginning:
Windows("I don’t know the name.xls").Activate
Sheets("Rapport 1").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("The File I Want To Put Data In.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Where I Want To Put It").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("I don’t know the name.xls").Close
‘How can I get the name?
```

I hope my statement is understandable.

Thank you very much in advance!

Have a nice day,

E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a list of the paths and the expected file masks. You can then loop each matching file and do your stuff.

```
Sub foo()
Dim request As String:  request = "01/2013"
'//make a date
Dim asDate   As Date:   asDate = "01/" & request
Dim dirs(2) As String, masks(2) As String

dirs(0) = "c:\xxx\dir1\"
masks(0) = "*" & Format$(asDate, "mmmmyyyy") & "*.xls"

dirs(1) = "c:\xxx\dir2\"
masks(1) = "*" & Format$(asDate, "mmmyyyy") & "*.xls"

dirs(2) = "c:\xxx\dir3\"
masks(2) = "*" & Format$(asDate, "mmyyyy") & "*.xls"

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(dirs)
    GetFiles dirs(i), masks(i)
Next
End Sub

Private Function GetFiles(path As String, mask As String)
Dim file As String
'//loop matching files
file = Dir$(path & mask)
Do Until Len(file) = 0
    '//process match
    process path & file
    file = Dir$()
Loop
End Function

Sub process(filePath As String)
    MsgBox "processing " & filePath
    'workbook.open
End Sub
```

As `"XXX-01/2013"` is not a file name I assumed `"XXX-012013"`. 
If its another subdirectory just:

```
dirs(x) = "c:\xxx\dir3\" & Format$(asDate, "mm") & "\"
masks(x) = "*" & year(asDate) & "*.xls"
```

Comment: Hello Alex,

Thank you for your answer!

It looks like a good direction to follow. I am going to adapt it and it should work fine.

Once again, thanks!

E.

Comment: I am working on it, I'll give you feedback as soon as I'm done.